# How to implement a Power BI visual in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powerbi

I have a report with multiple pages and multiple visuals on each page. I'd like to embed the visuals and not the report/page itself.

I followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embed-visual
but it seems like I'm doing something wrong. I'm getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: powerbi_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.embed is not a function
```

Here's my code

```
function myComponent() {
  let embedUrl = "<myReportEmbedUrl";

  let reportId = "<myReportId>";

  let accessToken = "<myToken>";

  useEffect(() => {
    const embedConfig = {
      type: "visual",
      tokenType: powerbi.models.TokenType.Aad,
      accessToken: accessToken,
      embedUrl: embedUrl,
      id: reportId,
      visualName: "The name of the chart I want to embed",
      pageName: "The name of the page inside the report",
    };

    const embedContainer = document.getElementById("visualContainer");
    const visual = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, embedConfig);

  }, [embedUrl, reportId]);

  return <div id="visualContainer"></div>;
}
```

Comment: Have you check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/powerbi-client-react. I think you need PowerBIEmbed from 'powerbi-client-react' instead of powerBI

Comment: This is where I got that code from... Do you have a working example of embeding a visual?

Answer (score 0):

You need PowerBIEmbed from 'powerbi-client-react' instead of powerBI library for embeding PowerBI as a component.

Working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-d3mtxn?file=App.tsx) here.
Focus on line 31,36,37. That all I change from their [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-react/blob/master/React/demo/src/DemoApp.tsx)

```
type: 'visual',
pageName: 'ReportSection600dd9293d71ade01765',
visualName: 'VisualContainer6',
```